# Error C2027 when trying to access enum-class class member

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve this C2027 compiler error:
"A type cannot be used until it is defined. To resolve the error, be sure the type is fully defined before referencing it".

This is CPU.h:

```
// CPU.h
#include "Register.h"

class Register;

class CPU
{
public:
    static const enum class Flag { CARRY = 4, HALF_CARRY, SUBTRACT, ZERO };

private:
    Register A;
};
```

And this is Register.h:

```
// Register.h
#include "CPU.h"

class CPU;

class Register 
{
    void foo(const CPU::Flag& flag); // error C2027
};
```

So I now that this error is because CPU class hasn't initialize yet and I'm aware of the option the put the **Flag** Enum class outside of CPU class. But I wonder if there is another option so I can keep Flag inside CPU.h
(for logic purposes).

Thanks :)

Comment: There is a mutual dependency between your class definitions. There is no other option than making one class definition independent of the other.

Comment: Now the question is why `Flag` is a member of your `CPU` class and `Register` isn't. This seems totally arbitrary.

Comment: You'll have to move the enum out of `CPU` class definition, and into its own header. Then `Register.h` would include `CPUFlag.h`, and `CPU.h` would include `Register.h`, and you won't have circular includes. You could then do `class CPU { using Flag = CPUFlag; };` and continue to use `CPU::Flag` in most places.